# a person's interests do [blank]?

Tags: single-word-requests

The prosecutor's interests would want him to believe the defendant guilty.

The prosecutor's interests persuade him to believe the defendant guilty.

The prosecutor's interests lead him to believe the defendant guilty.

Are the best I could come up with, but I was wondering if there was a more appropriate answer?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to describe?

Comment: I think it would be a bit odd to "personify" a person's "interests" so far as to say the interests themselves could actually ***want*** anything. In OP's context, even ***persuade*** seems like a personification too far. I'd stick to ***lead***, or maybe ***incline***.

Comment: The prosecutor's interests might predispose him to consider the defendant guilty.

Comment: This is all too passive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Odd, perhaps, but not too odd. Note, for instance, that the verbs are both active (Progressive is grammatical) and metaphoric (no physical leading, rhetorical persuasion, or emotions of the interests themselves are actually involved).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm going with FumbFingers answer of ***lead*** or ***incline***.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're in "court":

The prosecutor's interests [prejudice](https://www.wordnik.com/words/prejudice) him to believe the defendant guilty.

Answer (score 0):

The prosecutor's interests permitted him to believe the defendant guilty .